# Implementation of the python code for graph api to extract info of a instagram account to 5 instagram accounts

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token, instagram-graph-api

I have implemented the python code to extract the info of a particular account like username, post details using Instagram graph api I wan to implement the same to 5 Instagram accounts which are public, if possible
using only the graph api of a single account to access 5 accounts.

this i was trying for a single Instagram account--

```
import requests

# Replace with your Facebook access token
access_token = " "

# Replace with your Instagram Business Account ID
instagram_account_id = ""

# Get user media (posts) for Instagram using the combined API
media_url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{instagram_account_id}/media"
params_media = {
    "access_token": access_token,
    "fields": "id,caption,media_type,thumbnail_url,permalink,timestamp,like_count,comments_count,media_like_count,media_comments_count,impressions_1d,username,name,location",
}
response_media = requests.get(media_url, params=params_media)

# Check if the request was successful
if response_media.status_code == 200:
    media_data = response_media.json()

    # Get username and name from the first post
    first_post = media_data.get("data", [])[0]
    username = first_post.get("username", "")
    name = first_post.get("name", "")

    # Print username and name only once at the beginning
    print(f"Username: {username}")
    print(f"Name: {name}")

    # Get profile information for the Instagram Business Account
    profile_url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{instagram_account_id}?fields=profile_picture_url,followers_count,follows_count&access_token={access_token}"
    response_profile = requests.get(profile_url)

    if response_profile.status_code == 200:
        profile_data = response_profile.json()
        profile_picture_url = profile_data.get("profile_picture_url", "")
        followers_count = profile_data.get("followers_count", 0)
        follows_count = profile_data.get("follows_count", 0)
        print(f"Profile Picture URL: {profile_picture_url}")
        print(f"Followers Count: {followers_count}")
        print(f"Following Count: {follows_count}")

    else:
        print(f"Error getting profile information: {response_profile.status_code} - {response_profile.text}")

    # Print user media for Instagram
    print(f"\nUser Media:")
    num_posts = len(media_data.get("data", []))
    print(f"Number of Posts: {num_posts}")

    for post in media_data.get("data", []):
        post_id = post.get("id")
        caption = post.get("caption", "")
        timestamp = post.get("timestamp", "")
        like_count = post.get("like_count", 0)
        comments_count = post.get("comments_count", 0)
        media_type = post.get("media_type", "")
        media_permalink = post.get("permalink", "")
        media_like_count = post.get("media_like_count", 0)
        media_comments_count = post.get("media_comments_count", 0)
        impressions_1d = post.get("impressions_1d", 0)
        location = post.get("location", {}).get("name", "No Location")

        print(f"\nPost ID: {post_id}")
        print(f"Caption: {caption}")
        print(f"Timestamp: {timestamp}")
        print(f"Likes Count: {like_count}")
        print(f"Comments Count: {comments_count}")
        print(f"Media Type: {media_type}")
        print(f"Media Permalink: {media_permalink}")
        print(f"Media Like Count: {media_like_count}")
        print(f"Media Comments Count: {media_comments_count}")
        print(f"Impressions 1D: {impressions_1d}")
        print(f"Location: {location}")

    # Print list of followers
    followers_url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{instagram_account_id}/followers"
    params_followers = {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "fields": "name",
    }
    response_followers = requests.get(followers_url, params=params_followers)

    if response_followers.status_code == 200:
        followers_data = response_followers.json()
        followers_list = followers_data.get("data", [])

        if followers_list:
            print("\nFollowers:")
            for follower in followers_list:
                follower_name = follower.get("name", "")
                print(f"- {follower_name}")
        else:
            print("\nNo followers found.")

else:
    print(f"Error: {response_media.status_code} - {response_media.text}")
```